# Linux block-based bare-metal backup/restore

Tags: linux, backup

I am looking for a Linux solution which will get me back up and running in a few hours in the event of my laptop being stolen.

I already use `restic` for file-based cloud backups, but in this instance my use case is a bare-metal restore.

I want to be able to plug in an USB HDD and have only the blocks which have changed since the last backup copied to the external disk.

I'm only interested in blocks which contain useful data. Blocks not in a partition or which are fileystem "free space" should be excluded.

Ideally, I'd be able to use the backup as a mountable disk inside VMware or VirtualBox.

Open source products preferred.

Comment: Please clarify whether the goal is to back up *everything* on a disk, (including deallocated blocks of deleted files, blocks of old operating systems if the HD was used for one, *et al*), or just the files, the file-system metadata, and the partition metadata.

Comment: @agc Updated (to exclude unreferenced blocks). Thanks!